# “Available On Android” missing from Facebook App Details page

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook Developers account for my iPhone and Android mobile app and have setup an “App Details” page. Under “Apps”, “App Details”, the “App Center Listed Platforms” are shown as YES for iOS-iPhone and YES for Android. But when I go to my App Center page at https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/370304769678189 under Info, it says “Available On iPhone, iPad” but does not say “Available On Android”.

How do I fix? I have saved multiple times and even was able to successfully upload a video that now shows on the page.

Comment: You now seem to have "Android" available on the page you linked to. How did you get that to work?